# dataframe parsed as a tuple, when read from a pickle

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a pickle file which contains a dict of dataframes. As part of a data clean up script, I load this pickle and do additional processing to some, but not all of the dataframes, then overwrite the pickle to be picked up and loaded by simulation program later.

When I read the pickle after this processing, all but two of the values are correctly unpacked and parsed as dataframes, but the two are read as tuples. Since these two do not actually require any changes in this particular data cleanup script, they are not processed by the script beyond the following:

```
#start of script, read in the pickle assign the dfs for later use.
input_file = sys.argv[1]
with open(input_file, 'rb') as handle:
  data = pickle.load(handle)


trips      = data['trips']       # this sees additional processing, is correctly written out as a DF. 
stops      = data['stops']       # this sees additional processing, is correctly written out as a DF.
stop_times = data['stop_times'], # NO additional processing, is INCORRECTLY written out as a tuple.
road_segs  = data['road_segs'],  # NO additional processing, is INCORRECTLY written out as a tuple.
seg_props  = data['seg_props']   # NO additional processing, is correctly written out as a df.


... # do additional processing on trips and stops


#Output the update DFs and carry the unaltered DFs through to overwrite the original pickle.

data = {
  "trips":      trips,
  "stops":      stops,
  "stop_times": stop_times,
  "road_segs":  road_segs,
  "seg_props":  seg_props
}

with open(input_file, 'wb') as handle:
  pickle.dump(data, handle, protocol=4)
```

If I read the pickle before I run it though this script I get the following.

```
[type(val) for val in gtfs.values()]                                                                                                                                                    
#output
[pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 geopandas.geodataframe.GeoDataFrame,
 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame]
```

and after:

```
[type(val) for val in gtfs.values()]                                                                                                                                                    
Out[17]: 
[pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame,
 tuple,
 tuple,
 pandas.core.frame.DataFrame]
```

these tuples are highly nested too:

```
(((                                   trip_id stop_id  stop_duation
   0        15243854-AUG19-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01   17894           0.0
   1        15243854-AUG19-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01   17897           0.0
   2        15243854-AUG19-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01   17900           0.0

   [2812369 rows x 3 columns],),),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have two hanging commas

```
stop_times = data['stop_times'],
road_segs  = data['road_segs'],
```

in my import, that are causing this. How I didnt notice this after staring at it over and over is beyond me.